# TweenMax - How to animate an element with different speed?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm a newbie in TweenMax.js and I'm trying here to animate an element's opacity and position. I want to make the element appear in 0.5 seconds while the horizontal movement of the element should complete in 2 seconds.

This is what I've accomplished so far.

```
var tl = new TimelineMax(); 
tl.to('.elem', 2,{autoAlpha:1,x:0,ease:Power4.easeInOut});
```

I've tried this code but the horizontal movement animation starts only after the opacity animation

```
var tl = new TimelineMax();
tl.to('.elem', 2, {x:0,ease:Power4.easeInOut})
.to('.elem', 0.5, {autoAlpha:1});
```

> How can I get my element animated at different speeds by modifying the
>   existing code?

```js
var tl = new TimelineMax();
var e = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
e.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(/\S/g, '<span class="elem">$&</span>');
})
tl.to('.elem', 3, {
  autoAlpha: 1,
  x: 0,
  ease: Power4.easeInOut
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(-15px);
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(-5px);
}

span:nth-last-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(5px);
}

span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(10px);
}

span:nth-last-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(15px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of search, I finally found the solution.

https://greensock.com/forums/topic/10133-how-can-i-run-multiple-tweens-in-parallel-in-a-timeline/

> To have tweens run in parallel you need to insert them at the same
> point in time in the timeline.
>
> Where a tween is inserted into a timeline is controlled via the
> position parameter. In my example, I can have the second tween start
> at the same time as the first tween by **adding it at a time of 0** like
> this

```
 tl.to('.elem', 2,{autoAlpha:1,ease:Power4.easeInOut})
 .to('.elem', 4, {x:0,ease:Power2.easeIn}, 0)
```

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/BaQLypN)**

Answer (score 0):

I added `transition: opacity .5s; transition: transform 2s;` to the span element's CSS to change the duration of the two different transitions. 
You can read more about CSS transition properties here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

```js
var tl = new TimelineMax();
var e = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
e.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(/\S/g, '<span class="elem">$&</span>');
})
tl.to('.elem', 3, {
  autoAlpha: 1,
  x: 0,
  ease: Power4.easeInOut
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(-15px);
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(-5px);
}

span:nth-last-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(5px);
}

span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(10px);
}

span:nth-last-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(15px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My last resort will be css for sure. But I'm wondering if there is a solution in js.

Comment: No problem :) You should update your question to say which language you require and remove the [css] tag so you don't get a bunch of CSS answers. Happy coding!